How to debug a yarn workspaces webpack based TypeScript monorepo in WebStorm
Given a yarn workspaces with an app and multiple libraries all built with webpack 5, how do I debug with WebStorm or IntelliJ so that I can hit a breakpoint in a library?
I'm hosting with webpack-dev-server 4
I can hit breakpoints in the final app workspace package, but not in dependent libraries. We have to use Chrome Dev Tools currently.
Is there some trick to getting the JetBrains debugger to recognize workspaces?
